# SQL/T-SQL Substring LEFT or Right doesn't appear to resolve

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a two table where I have some values in a column UniqueKeys such as:

***Table 1***

- 2016_2016-2 S2_001840_30_01
- 2017_2017-2 D4_002213_3_01

The problem is that I am trying to match these with table 2 Unique values where the values are written in a different order such as :

***Table 2:***

- 001840_2016-2_S2_30_D_179_364128_400985
- 002213_2017-2_D4_3_E_752_376901_422828

Table 1 is from a different source system and table 2 is from different one. What I am trying to achieve is create a new table ***TABLE 3*** where when the unique values match between table 1 and table 2 then insert the data from certain columns of table 1 and 2 into table 3 or else ignore the rest.

The way the Unique values should be is the following:

- Year and Period: 2016-2
- Cycle : S2
- Unit: 001840
- Group: 30

Giving the end result in Table 3 as:

- 001840_2016-2_S2_30
- 002213_2017-2_D4_3

Comment: Create a function receives those two values as input and returns a boolean and use it on the on clause, use it to populate your new relation table

Answer (score 0):

You need to split both input values by "_" and then recombine the parts in the way they lead to the same format. Then you can join the tables.

Use two functions, the first one for values from type table 1, the second for values from table 2.

Effekt:

```
SELECT ...
FROM table1
     JOIN table2 ON splitfunction1(table1.Key1) = splitfunction2(table2.Key2);
```